# Not able to run pybot batch file in cygwin in windows environment

Tags: python, shell, batch-file, cygwin, robotframework

I am running a shell script in cygwin where I am using python robot framework, but in that environment it's not getting 'pybot' as command.

```
$ pybot --version
```

Result-

```
-bash: pybot: command not found
```

However in cmd prompt the above command is working fine.

PS- I have already set python interpreter path in environment variable. As the same command is working fine in cmd prompt. Is there any possible way to use pybot in cygwin shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have explored and get to know that, in Cygwin we need to specify the file type as well. So, if we say-

```
pybot.bat --version
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me in cygwin:

Adjetterpc@Pompina

$ robot.bat --version
Robot Framework 3.0.4 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)

Adjetterpc@Pompina

$ pybot.bat --version
Robot Framework 3.0.4 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)